# How can I get a YouTube channel representing my business deleted?

Tags: youtube

An old co-director who has since passed away uploaded some videos to a YouTube channel named after our business and I want to get these deleted.

I have tried resetting his password as I have access to his e-mail account but he must have used another e-mail address as the account that I've managed to reset does not own this particular channel.

How can I do this? There doesn't seem to be an easy method to e-mail a human being at YouTube and I want these videos representing my business removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly ask his family to close the account: https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/6357590?hl=en

Or, probably easier, you can claim that the channel is impersonating your business or file copyright takedowns for individual videos to get the channel closed.